# Why is using a truly random function in a fixed length encryption scheme not efficient?

Tags: block-cipher, pseudo-random-function

I am working through Katz and Lindell, and Theorem 3.26 in the book proves that a construction based on a PRF is CPA-secure.  The thrust of the scheme is that if $F_k$ is a PRF, with $k, m, r \in \{0, 1\}^n$ (key, message, random-string), then $c = (r, F_k(r) \oplus m)$.

The idea behind the proof is to first prove the security of the scheme using a truly random function $f_n$ in place of the PRF $F_k$, and then show that if the scheme is not secure using PRF $F_k$, then $F_k$ can be distinguished from a truly random function.

In the proof, the authors remark that the encryption scheme which uses the truly random function $f_n$ in place of PRF $F_k$ *is not a legal encryption scheme, "because it is not efficient"*.  I am wondering if someone can explain to me why this is the case?  I would think the scheme would still be efficient, because even though the description of the truly random function $f_n$ is long, using it to determine which points map to what should be fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a truly random function $F:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$. By a basic argument in combinatorics, writing down a description of $F$ takes $n2^n$ bits. Concretely, we often want $n\approx 128$ (plausibly this could be smaller in the information theoretic setting though, say 80 on the low end). This is already *significantly* more storage than is available in any practical situations.

This is to say that even storing a description of the relevant function is infeasible. If we store the function as a lookup table of $2^n$ entries, then indexing into it (in constant time) takes exponentially long, ie the function is slow to compute as well.

Comment: I see.  So we do not have a "hash function" for example that can efficiently lookup the input and determine the output in the table?

Comment: The primary concern is storage, everything else doesn't matter. A terabyte is $2^{40}$ bytes, or $2^{43}$ bits. To store the aforementioned random function, you would need devices to have $\approx 2^{80}$ terabytes of storage to devote to solely storing the aforementioned random function.

Comment: There are other issued as well (evaluation efficiency, and that "uniformly random" is not a property that third parties can verify, so there is a trust assumption), but the primary issue is that no computers on earth could possibly store the function.

Comment: But this primarily seems to be a practical concern, and strictly working with the definitions, there is no limitation in terms of storage -- only the speed at which the function evaluates an input with respect to the magnitude of the security parameter

Comment: There is a limitation in terms of definitions, due to the constant time evaluation issue I mentioned earlier. Moreover, one can (directly) have there be an issue in terms of complexity theory as well, but it is dependent on the underlying computational model in subtle ways. For example, evaluation time will be exponentially bad in standard TM models. In RAM models it may be faster, but RAM models are not thought to be realistic in the setting of extremely high storage for precisely the reasons described in this post (in particular, one can argue that the RAM model violates causality)

Comment: This violation is simply because if you can index into any piece of memory in unit time, you can in particular do this between so axially a separated pieces of memory faster than light. This issue doesn't really matter for "small" memory settings (where the violation is small), but when one starts talking about $2^{80}$ terabytes the issue gets larger. This is also ignoring that one can prove computational lower bounds for some models of random functions, namely random circuits.

Comment: All of this is to say that there are many issues with this from a theoretical perspective, but they are dependent on the underlying model of computation. But the practical issue is the same for everything - the construction should not be reasonable, as it requires more storage than any single device can have, and likely than all devices humanity has ever created has.

Comment: why would it be slow to compute? Assumninh random acceas memory it ahould be fast if you are usinh peta bytes of storage on magnetic drives you will obviously have high latency but with RAM it should be a trivial lookup.

Comment: @MeirMaor if you do not scan through the entire memory describing the function, you start being vulnerable to cache attacks. Still though, I am of the opinion that (even in a RAM model) indexing into an array storing $2^{80}$ terabytes of data is intrinsically slow. In particular, under most reasonable assumptions about how the data is (physically) laid out, you'll start running into speed-of-light lower bounds. For example, if laid out linearly, with 1 inch for each terabyte, it will require $\approx 10^{19}$ miles of space, which takes at least $\approx 95$ million years to traverse

Comment: without violating causality. You could try to optimize space (into some 3d shape rather than 1d shape), but the numbers are too big to be reasonable in any setting. One can attempt to formalize this in various computational models, but the argument is different in each computational model, and frankly any computational model that admits computations this large is not based in the real world.